# Regex: C# extract questions within a text

Tags: c#, regex, extract

I need a Regex to detect questions within a text.

Example input:

> please, tell me **how to do this**... or **how to make it right**! and so on....

I need output:

> 1. how to do this
> 2. how to make it right

Now I use this:
`` (?<q>(how to|how match|how many).*)(\s|\.|;|!|\?|( \-)|(\- )|‾|:|…|_|\||@|~|…|–|—|¯|»|•|●|{|}|\(|\)|\\|\]|\[|>|<|→|'|""|`|$) `` but does not work

I need only **how to** questions

Comment: What about _"He didn't know **how to do this**"_? That's not a question.

Comment: Do not try to parse natural language with regular expressions. Just stop. It will not work.

Comment: I need only **how to** questions

Comment: Yes, but you need only "how to" **questions**

Comment: Regex is only the 1'st step in process... so I need not very clean result

Comment: I cannot tell you how to do something which cannot be done.

Comment: So you want anything that has "how to" in it, then? That's easy: `.*how to.*`. Will give you way more than you want, but hey, it's what you asked for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The task you are trying to accomplish falls under a different category than what regular expressions are good for.

To solve the problem of extracting arbitrary questions from text you need a lot more than just a few good regular expressions. You should start looking at a good natural language processing toolkit. And maybe first do some Part of Speech tagging. Then, from there you will need to do some syntax and sentence parsing and then move on to try to answer the question of: "Is this a sentence a question?" by examining each sentence your NLP pipeline will have identified.

Armed with this knowledge, at a minimum, you should understand that the task you want to accomplish is rather difficult and while not impossible will require a lot of fine tuning to get good performance (usually measured with [Accuracy and Precision metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision)). You will most likely not get anywhere near 100% on either but you should be able to get decent results with a good PoS tagger and a good sentence parser.

**EDIT**

In light of your recent edit to the question, you may be able to get some basic coverage with RegExs and hand-written rules but you will still fail to differentiate many more complicated cases. The natural language processing toolkit route is still preferred for a more generic solution.

Don't spend too much time trying to come up with a *silver bullet* regular expression to match natural language. *Natural language is **not regular** - so it's not going to work!* It's ok to use regular expressions to identify some keywords but beyond that you're better off with simple hand-written rules, and tokenizing in lue of a good natural language pipeline..

**UPDATE**

If you're really serious about this task, have a look at [sharpnlp.codeplex.com](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/) as a starting point. There are other NLP tool-kits out there with [NLTK](http://nltk.org/) springing to mind as a popular one if you're not required to use C#. As a second step, get yourself an introductory book on NLP. The subject is vast and really cool. A great book I've learned a lot from would be: [Speech and Language Processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131873210) by Jurafski and Martin.

And as a final thought, here's what I would do at a minimum:

1. perform normalization (remove any symbols that you don't need, and duplicates)
2. try to do basic sentence segmentation (split at punctuation: `. , ; ? !`)
3. convert all letters to lowercase
4. replace all numbers with a tag (i.e. )
5. perform Part of Speech tagging on each of the normalized sentences
6. then you can move on to try to determine where all the "how to" questions are located in the text.
7. after you have your locations you should be able to map them back to the original text and extract the original "How To" questions from there

Good luck!

Comment: You're welcome. I realize it's not telling you how to craft a RegEx for your task but I think in the long run it's better to understand the limitations of a tool than waste a lot of time searching for an answer where is none..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help. It can detect direct question, that is sentences which end with question marks.

```
@"[^\.!]*?(?!\?)"
```

This matches every character except dots, question mark and exclamation mark until a question mark is found (note the * quantifier which is greedy and a negative lookahead for the question mark)

Answer (score 0):

I can not tell you how to parse all questions.  This will give you some possible questions, which you could parse, but some questions will be missed.  Other sentences that are not questions might get selected when they are not questions.  Is that OK?

```
([^\.?!]*(?:how|what|where|when|why)[^\.?!]*[\.?!]|[^\.?!]*\?)
```

Run that on the above text and it returns:

I can not tell you **how** to parse all questions.
Other sentences that are not questions might get selected **when** they are not questions.
Is that OK**?**